# How to realize navigatable tabs with Aurelia which preserve state?

Tags: tabs, aurelia

Following scenario:

[image]

Tabs can come and go. My current idea which I am trying to figure out is to have a `<router-view>` for each tab. A `name`d `<router-view>` to be exact. When a tab needs to be added I want to dynamically add a route with the `viewPorts` property set to the corresponding `<router-view>` name.
Depending on the currently opened tab I show or hide `<router-view>`s.

Will this work? Am I missing something?
Do you have other/better approaches to implement this and/or can provide links to examples?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you have only one `router-view` and custom-elements in each tab. If they have too much information you can load data   when changing the tabs

Comment: Hm, will this work? I mean the custom elements/components are navigatable which the button should indicate, in this case the view routes to another view and the whole content of the "tab" needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a much cleaner way by using a child router. You can configure the child router like this in your parent component's ts/js file:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router){
    config.map([
        { route: 'tab-1', name: 'tab-1', moduleId: 'tab-1/tab-1', nav: 'true', title: 'Tab 1' },
        { route: 'tab-2', name: 'tab-1', moduleId: 'tab-2/tab-2', nav: 'true', title: 'Tab 2' },
        { route: 'tab-3', name: 'tab-3', moduleId: 'tab-3/tab-3', nav: 'true', title: 'Tab 3' }
    )
}
```

Make every tab a custom element, in the above code I named them 'tab-*'.

You can then go ahead and create a new component for your tabbed navigation (you can always put the navigation logic in the parent component but I find this approach to be cleaner, mode modular and reusable)

**tabnav.ts**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

export class TabnavCustomElement{
    @bindable router: Router;
}
```

**tabnav.html**

```
<template>
<ul>
    <li repeat.for="navItm of router.navigation">
        <a href.bind="navItm.href" class="nav-link ${navItm.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">${navItm.title}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The you can go to **parent.html** and include it like this:

```
<tabnav router.bind="router"></tabnav>
<router-view></router-view>
```

The `<router-view>` will then change according to what the tab that you click on. If you want to share state between the tabs you can create a shared service which you can inject on each of the three custom elements.

Also every time you want to add a new tab you simply create a new custom element for that tab and place it in the router. It's the navigation component's responsibility then, to show it on screen

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Thing is that this solution only has a single `<router-view>` which means that there is only a single rendering container for all tabs, right? And one thing that I have to solve is that the state of the tab should not be gone if I switch between the tabs. Because of that my thought was to have multiple named `<router-views>` which is specifically targeted by a tab route via `viewPorts` (configurable in the route definition).

Comment: Will try it out.

Comment: @timmkrause Yes, you will only have one router-view for all tabs but as I mentioned in my answer you can save that state in an injectable service shared by the communicating tabs.